# Sending a value to another ViewModel and async

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
public async void GetUserInfo()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn =
            new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connect"].ConnectionString))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            using (SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand("SELECT * from XTable", conn));
            {

                using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    if (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        Code_abc = reader.GetInt32(0);

                    reader.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

and:

```
public XViewModel(int UserID)
{  
    GetUserInfo();
    EmployeListBox = new[]
    {
        new EmployeListBoxItems(PackIconKind.UndoVariant, "Listing", new YWindow( new YViewModel(Code_abc)) ),
    };
    Console.WriteLine("3");   
}
```

When I see the debug output

```
3
1
```

I'm not sure If this has something to do with the ASYNC or not but according to the debug output, I'm creating the form and It's ViewModel and then getting the results for the query, so basically `code_abc` I'm sending is being sent as 0 instead of the actual value.

Why is that happening If I'm calling `GetUserInfo` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't `await` `GetUserInfo()` it returns before "1" is being printed to the console.

For you to be able to `await` the method, you should change its return type from `void` to `Task`:

```
public async Task GetUserInfo()
```

But even then you won't be able to `await` it like this from a constructor:

```
await GetUserInfo();
...
Console.WriteLine("3");
```

You should not call `async` methods from a constructor.

If you call it like this from a method marked as `async`, you should see "1" being printed to the console before "3" though:

```
public async Task SomeAsyncMethod (int UserID)
{
    await GetUserInfo();
    EmployeListBox = new[]
    {
        new EmployeListBoxItems(PackIconKind.UndoVariant, "Listing", new YWindow( new YViewModel(Code_abc)) ),
    };
    Console.WriteLine("3");
}
```

Comment: The listbox should be in the Constructor however, so how I'm supposed to get the value of code_abc using GetUserInfo() because from what I see, I'm creating the YWindow and YViewModel before GetUserInfo gets the code_abc.

Comment: If for example, I set the EmployeListBox in the GetUserInfo, the value will pass however, the GUI won't show the ListBox.